Yellow Common Wire - Universal Blower Motor - Wiring Question
I am trying to help a family member out with a new blower motor. This is for a 2008 Goodman AURF363616 air handler. The old motor had two wires (one brown, one black) and a jumper wire connected to the capacitor and transformer. Reading the diagram, it appears that only the solid brown, and the brown/white is connected to the capacitor. Would that mean that the yellow should go directly to the transformer, control board, or tied off?
They currently have the Yellow running to the capacitor with the solid Brown on the second leg. The jumper wire from the old motor is on the same leg as the Yellow, and the fan did not come on.
The only other wires from the old set up was that the speed wires were connected to the relay on the control board. Any help would be appreciated.

https://imgur.com/a/Pmomhan

How about a picture of the wiring diagram on the motor nameplate?

According to the wiring diagram on the motor the yellow wire will be one leg of your 240V, this is the wire that will always be providing 120V to the motor. This should be connected to L1.
The second leg of your 240V should come from either the black, blue, or red wires. This should be decided by the relay on the board. If there are less than 3 speed settings on the relay, match up either the HI/MED/LOW in the same fashion as the old motor and wire nut off the extra speed tap.
The brown and brown/white wires will be connect to either side of your 5mfd run capacitor. There should only be 2 possible connections on you run capacitor and it does not matter which color goes to which connection.
The purple and orange wires control the direction of rotation. If you fire up the blower and the wheel is spinning the wrong direction, turn off the power and flip the connections so that the purples and oranges are connected.

Wire nut is "Marret" not "merit".
